# How to subclass QVector?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qvector

I have a class named Symbol and I would like to create a QVector subclass (Symbols) to add some useful methods. But when I use Symbols from another class A, the compiler gives the error 'Symbols does not name a type'.

```
class Symbols: public QVector< Symbol >
{
public:
    Symbols() {}

    // Useful methods
    QSymbol findSymbol(const QString &name);

    // ...
};

class A
{
private:
    Symbols symbols;
};
```

Is it correctly subclassed?

Why appears 'Symbols does not name a type' when compiles class A?

Comment: You're missing ;'s at the end of your class declarations

Comment: Didn't you forget to include the symbols.h (where Symbols class declared)? And your idea to sub class QVector looks rather strange.

Comment: Sorry for missing the ; in the sample. On the original code has the ;. And, yes, the class A has the symbols.h on the include.

Comment: @mabg, are your classes defined in the same order as you wrote in your question: `A` defined **after** `Symbols` class??

Answer (score 9):

It's usually ill advised to derive from a container. You almost always want a "Has A" relationship otherwise your class will expose members that users of your class can use which may corrupt the state.

Also it looks like you're trying to implement a look up in your class which means perhaps QMap  or QHash would be a more appropriate container

Comment: This is just wrong. QStringList is a very good example for subclassing. You do not have much experience with it, do you? Also, you do not actually address the compilation issue by any means.

Comment: The Symbol class have different properties, so I would like to find it for these properties. One of them is name. QMap or QHash could be better for speed reasons, but I'll need more methods to search, so, finally I'll do the same, subclass a QMap or QHash.

Comment: QStringList is not a good example for inheritance. It extends an instantiation of QList<QString> with some methods working on QString, but does not, and cannot override any virtual function. This has several problems. First of all, the base class QList does not have a virtual destructor meaning that is not meant to be a base class. Then, QList does not have virtual functions, so there is no room for type-specific behavior in subclasses which is all that inheritance is about. Extending the interface should be done by prodiving free functions taking a QList<QString> parameter.

Comment: @Jens: please start with reading the QStringLit documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html It is adding convenience around QList<QString> without **any** need for virtualism. Can you understand that subclassing is not just about virtualism, but also about inheriting existing methods **as is**? It is C++, and it is not a Qt specific thing. The whole virtual destructor argument is moot as there is no virtual method in question here.

Comment: Well, yes, it will save you few keystokes, that's for sure. If the using inheritance is perfectly fine for that, why people bothered introducing `UFCS` (in D) or extension methods (in `C#`)?

Comment: And, even in C++, it is preferable just to write function `QSymbol findSymbol(const QVector<QSymbol>&, const QString& name)`.

Comment: @Lazlo I do clearly understand what QStringList is, and id addition, I also clearly udnerstand what inheritance in C++ is. The whole virtual destructor argument is about destruction of objects, not if it has other virtual functions. Without a virtual destructor, the following code does not call the correct destructor: `QList* a = new QStringList(); delete a;` This calls only `~QList()`, so if QStringList has any members or acquires some resources, there will be leak. Good luck with code like this! That is also why you should never inherit from STL containers.

Comment: @Lazlo And given the fact that we are talking about C++, QStringList is a specialization of the QList<T> template.

Comment: @Jens: just as the OP's code is the specialization of QVector<T> ... I would still kindly suggest to look into QStringList more and how widely and well used it is. Moreover, you are drawing hypothetical cases that `if ...` , but there is no any if. It is what it is without being more that you may read into.

Comment: Actually I have been programming Qt for the last four years professionally, so I know QStringList and used it a lot. It is not the only case where Qt3 has problems with inheritance, e.g. QTextStream and QTextIStream have an issue. I don't think that my case is so hypthetical. The designer of QList did not anticipate that it is used as a base-class, but guess what? Somebody did and implemented QStringList! Now, a user sees this and decides to implement its own class by inheriting from QList, but this time it has members. This is just not a good design, there is nothing to argue.

Comment: @Jens: show the additional member in the question please that has to be destructed and then we can talk. Until that, it is hypothetical. QStringList exists for a very valid reason, but go tell the Qt developers it does not make any sense like you doing here.

Comment: @LaszloPapp `QList* l = new QStringList(); delete l`. Any example where you delete a QStringList through a pointer to QList will be undefined behavior. That is what the C++ standard says, and Qt is still a C++ framework. I did open a bug a while ago, but it was rejected because fixing it would break binary compatibility.

Comment: @Jens: have no any idea why you would write that with sane thinking... Even any insane person would use it, it would have no effect as QStringList does not have members to destruct. Moreover, Qt 5 did break BC, so it seems your concern was not valid enough to address. Misinterpreting the "C++ standard" will not help.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Ok, suppose I write a class which takes a QList* in the constructor and stores the pointer. In the destructor, I delete the object because it is mine. No you feed it with a QStringList. See where this is going? To my knowledge, QStringList is only in the Qt3 compatibility files, so in a way they fixed for Qt5

Comment: Wait, what... It is a fundamental class in Qt 5's corelib/tools ! https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/0a0cc6afc8be1ab38367ad803a303f35f29ed5de:src/corelib/tools

Comment: @LaszloPapp Ok, I misinterpreted the doc. It only has some compatiblity members. But still, the design IS broken. It violates Liskov substitutability because I cannot put a QStringList everywhere a QList is used. See my example in the last comment. I don't think we will ever reach an agreement on this, and I suppose you as an experienced developer have read the numerous articles and guidelines why you should never inherit from such classes because it will cause undefined behavior. Should we agree to disagree?

Comment: Again, QStringList is just a convenience wrapper with additional methods. It does not have any additional data members. That is also precisely what the OP wanted. Please show me any authoritative article which says that causes any leaks. We can agree to disagree, but IMHO, you are just incorrect asserting memory leak when there is none.

Comment: @LaszloPapp 1. Liskov substition is violated. That is a language-agnostic major design issue. 2. Do you accept the C++ standard as an authoritative article? It says in section 5.3. that deleting an object with a non-virtual destructor through a base-class pointer is undefined behavior, e.g. it may leak. 3. Herb Sutter: " A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual.". From http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm, published in  C/C++ Users Journal, 19(9), September 2001 and repeated in C++ Coding Standards by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu.

Comment: You are continuously misinterpreting the standard... It _may_ leak, but it does _not_ in this case since it has no data member. I have just run it on several machines as well with different scenarios, but valgrind gave no any leak. I have no clue what you are talking about. I think you are trying to pick up a rule over-zealously and force that universally even in scenarios where it was not meant to apply.

Comment: @LaszloPapp The compiler may do anything in case undefined behavior. It may leak, crash, start another program, format your hard drive etc. It may work now, but stop working tomorrow when the compiler changes, different switches are used. You cannot rely on this, so it is best to avoid it. And what about the Liskov principle? Inheritance should always respect that, but it does not.

Comment: @LaszloPapp do you have a copy of "C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices"? Read item 35.

Comment: No, the standard says undefined behavior as an overall thing. That is, I cannot see how it is undefined behavior without data member, but you are free to show any implementation where that crashes. I think the compiler authors would have been shot in head already. :-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp It just doesn't matter if there is a member variable.  I think we have a different understanding of how a programming language works. The standard says it is undefined behavior, so I would not make any assumptions on the observed behavior. It is just not reliable. What any implementation does is not important. from what I get, you consider an actual implementation to define the semantics of a programming language. That is fine, but it may be different in later version of the compiler or completely different on other compiler. I would never deliberately rely on this.

Comment: @LaszloPapp What about the Liskov substitution principle? Violating it is a bad decision because what you state in your program does not hold and anybody reasoning about the program will come to wrong conclusions.

Comment: You cannot back up your claim on the implementation side. Why would anyone implement this as undefined behavior? In fact, this may even be fixed in the upcoming standard since it does not make much sense to get it undefined behavior in all cases, at least to me.

Comment: I don't have to back up my claim on any implementation. The standard defines it for me, and all implementations have to comply. That is what a standard is for. It defines the semantics of the language on all implementations, leaving some stuff undefined. And I do not use undefined decisions.

Comment: To quote "Avoid inheriting from classes that were not designed to be base-classes" in C++ Coding standards: http://books.google.de/books?id=mmjVIC6WolgC&pg=PT223&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false: "This undefined behavior might seem to be tolerated by your compiler and memory allocator, but it leaves you in the dark swamp of silent errors, memory leaks, heap corruption and porting nightmares". I prefer to avoid that.

Comment: You prefer to argue. There is no any memory leak, and no sane compiler would sneak memory leak into that cannot be memory-leaky. Your interpretation of the standard being perfect and all compilers always all trust bugs is strange. In fact, clang was prominent about not complying with rightfully buggy standard words here and there. Even if any compiler made your program crash, which I simply cannot believe, you would never ever write such an ugliness for QStringList since that shows no information about how it is meant to be used.

Comment: But yeah, you are free to provide valid use cases, that is, not what technically can be done, but actual and valid use cases out there. Even if you could do (which I question at this point), the API dictates how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: I do not assume the standard is perfect, but it defines how a C++ program works. Could you elaborate on your comment "you would never ever write such an ugliness for QStringList since that shows no information about how it is meant to be used". I do not understand what you mean. The definition of QStringList explicitly says that I can use it anywhere a QList is used (as pointer), but that fails.

Comment: (Final?) notice: Qt recognized it as a problem and proposes  to fix it in Qt6: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/16416. There is even a note in the official Qt documentation about it.

Answer (score 4):

After these comments, I must add this to the answer. **Don't inherit from `QVector<T>`**. That type doesn't have virtual destructor, and the most important thing in the inheritance (`IS-A`) relationship will be broken in that case.

Look into your class Symbols, and imagine you've over time increased complexity of it, so now you have destructor and constructor somewhere:

```
class Symbols: public QVector<Symbol>
{
    ~Symbols()
    {
        important_cleanup_here();
    }
};
```

You might think that `Symbols` is a subtype of `QVector<Symbol>`, so one of your clients write something like this:

```
QVector<Symbol>* symbols = new Symbols();
```

Sound good, right? After all, `Symbols` extends `QVector<Symbol>`, so it can follow substitute principle, right? **Wrong.** Because `QVector<T>` destructor is not virtual, this will not call `Symbols` destructor!

```
delete symbols;
```

Worse than that, this is undefined behavior and compiler could do whatever he feels like.

If you just want convenient method, create a non-method which will do the trick for you

```
QSymbol findSymbol(const QVector<QSymbol>&, const QString& name);
```

(for the reference on this, read this amazing Scott Meyer's article: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197)

In your example, of course, there's nothing to be scared of. But why putting such a burden on one of your classes, when you can use composition without any fear?

Also, refer to this (and few others) reported bug on this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-8292

Other than all other problems, I can see one right here:

```
class Symbols: public QVector<Symbol>
{
      QSymbol findSymbol(const QString &name);
};
```

Based on what I see, it should be either

```
class Symbols: public QVector<Symbol>
{
      Symbol findSymbol(const QString &name);
};
```

or

```
class Symbols: public QVector<QSymbol>
{
      QSymbol findSymbol(const QString &name);
};
```

Comment: This is not enough to solve the issue, and if you enumerate everything, you get to my answer which was already posted before this... Also, proposing the name QSymbol as a potential solution is a very very bad idea.

Comment: With this particular issue edited into the post minute later? I'm pretty sure this is the issue, and I'm also pretty sure that *it's a* bad idea subclassing collections (take a look of `std::queue`). In this case *favor composition over inheritance.*

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong. The whole purpose of QStringList (among other examples) - as mentioned -, is to provide convenience methods which is exactly what the OP wants, and no, if you check the history my answer was already submitted with working code when your answer was coming up, at least on my screen, either way, this cannot possibly compile without even a single QVector include (without which, template compiler error messages would be reasonable). That being said, I do not see the point of answer duplication.

Comment: Well, I can see multiple issues with that (the first and most dangerous that comes to my mind is lack of virtual destructor in `QVector` which makes entire `is-a` thing flawed).

Comment: Except that there is *no* runtime polymorphism for virtual methods intended as the OP clearly stated that. He only wants to add convenience methods, so no virtual destructor is pretty much a no issue, especially without virtual methods in QVector. Perhaps, you can read upon how virtual destructors work? The basic principle is that you start using them when you have at least one virtual method. You have _zero_ in this scenario.

Comment: I do know how virtual destructors work, thank you. Perhaps you should read why you should favor non-member functions here. Also, I'm sure you can't see that in this example he's also not sealing the class, so the client could find very practical to inherit it once more and to add few virtual methods, why not, when he is allowing that?

Comment: Show me one example of inheritance for QStringList... You are speaking against an established pattern in the Qt world. Please take your time and open up its implementation to see how these thing are done in the Qt world. This thread is getting needlessly unwieldy due to purist ultimate statements. The world is simply not black and white.

Comment: Oh, I can write one real quick. Do you really want me to write it? Even Qt states that it is broken, and the fix is out of the scope (and practically impossible because of binary compatibility), I don't know why you're complaining on that. You *really* want to create more bugs in this world with your advices?

Comment: Again, you are misinformed. Qt **did** break binary compatibility several times between major versions for issues that had to be fixed. And no, QStringList was not (for good!) among them at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

The problem was that I had a circular dependence.

Class Symbols:

```
#ifndef SYMBOLS_H
#define SYMBOLS_H
#include <QVector>
#include "A.h"
#include "symbol.h"

class Symbols: public QVector<Symbol>
{
public:
    Symbols() {}
};
#endif // SYMBOLS_H
```

Class A:

```
#include "symbols.h"
class A {
   private:
     QSymbols symbols;
}
```

The #include "A.h" provokes the error. It was there because I had a function with a reference to the class A. I must to search how to resolve circular references :).

Thank you very much to everyone.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, the next time I'll be more careful. Sometimes the C++ errors are so cryptic that mislead rather than help.

Comment: @mabg: it is not about the C++ errors, but the fact that you cannot simply paste your code whatever you have, or even a simple test case, reproducing the issue, and this misleads people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score -1):

You are having a couple of issues why your code does not compile:

- Missing the semi-colons after the class declarations, provided they are in the same file. Failing that, you would of course need to include the header file containing the Symbol's declaration into your file using it.
- You are using QSymbol return value instead of Symbol.
- You are not including QVector.

Here is a compiling code.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QVector>

class Symbol
{
};

class Symbols: public QVector<Symbol>
{
    public:
      Symbols() {}

      Symbol findSymbol(const QString &name) {}
};


class A {
       Symbols symbols;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build

```
qmake && (n)make
```

That being said, QSymbol looks fishy, too, as there is no such a class in Qt, and you really should not take names like that since that only causes confusion. Also, starting all the classes with a prefix is just silly, and only around in Qt for compatibility reasons, not because it is better than namespaces.

Also, please do not buy the argument that it is ultimately a bad idea to subclass containers. `QStringList` is a good example to prove that claim wrong.

Comment: Sorry for missing the ; in the sample. On the original code has the ;. And, yes, the class A has the symbols.h on the include.

Comment: The Symbol class have different properties, so I would like to find it for these properties and I don't want to have some global functions. So I have thought in a subclass of the container (QVector) with additional methods.

Comment: @LaszloPapp, how can this compile `Symbol findSymbol(const QString &name) {}`?

Comment: @vahancho: ideaone does not understand what you are referring to, either, http://ideone.com/QtjzXQ

Comment: @downvoter Seriously, **grow up**. If you want to make people annoyed, then please don't do it here.